# Can't write dataframe to influxdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, influxdb, influxdb-python

I'm trying to write the following dataframe to influxdb using the `DataFrameClient` in the python driver.

```
                     change  price symbol  volume
Time
2019-05-09 10:00:00       1     22   ABCD     450
2019-05-09 10:00:00       2      4   ABCD    2000
2019-05-09 10:00:00       3      1   ABCD    2000
2019-05-09 10:00:00       4      4   ABCD   13000
```

Since there duplicate timestamps I'm trying to edit the tags so that influx doesn't overwrite existing records. I tried the method in the documentation which is this:

```
client.write_points(result, tags={'price': pd[['price']]}
                    database='example', measurement='raw')
```

But I'm getting an error saying:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
>   a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I then tried to use the `tag_columns` parameter instead and pass in a list of columns that influx should use as tags but then when I looked in the measurement I saw that influx created new columns with a `_1` suffix which contain the data and the original columns are empty:

```
time                 change price price_1 symbol volume volume_1
----                 ------ ----- ------- ------ ------ --------
2019-05-09T10:00:00Z 3            1       ABCD          2000
2019-05-09T10:00:00Z 2            4       ABCD          2000
2019-05-09T10:00:00Z 4            4       ABCD          13000
2019-05-09T10:00:00Z 1            22      ABCD          450
```

Answer (score 0):

After some googling and searching through the github issues. I figured this out. The first problem (the error) is a known bug apparently and it doesn't have on v4.1.1 (I tried downgrading to check). The second problem with the suffixes was fixed when I dropped the entire database and recreated it.